# Can I have a different workflow when using nested_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested-forms

I'm using the gem nested_form by Ryan Bates. I'm a bit confused about the workflow for the user.

I'm supposed to have a "f.link_to_add" call, that will dynamically add a nested structure for the association. That works as advertised, but I feel that it is cumbersome for the user to FIRST click "Add Book" (as in the commonly used Author/Books example) and THEN type in the new Book fields.

I would like to have an empty set of Book fields shown initially, and if the user fills them and clicks Save, the are added to the Author.

How would I use the nested_form gem to achieve this scenario?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out `build`.  For example, your `new` action for your author could have something like:

```
@author = Author.new
@author.books.build
```

Note that if an author could only have one book rather than multiple you'd do something like this instead:

```
@author = Author.new
@author.build_book
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that nested_form is not suitable for this particular workflow.

It's easier achieved with a separate form for the associated class where you in the controller lookup the parent class (Author) and in the Book form keep a hidden field (:author_id in this example).

This only works if you can accept to add Books one by one.

Nested_form is more suitable when you really want to show a long list of Books and let the user have the option of adding/removing multiple items before Saving.